# JSPM: Error locating github:component/global/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz

Tags: angularjs, github, jspm, web-frontend, npm-install

I've spent the entire day trying to make jspm install a few libraries I'm required to as devDependencies. Unfortunately my frontend skills are not as good as my backend skills so that's why I'm asking for help.

I'm trying to add the **browser-sync** package, specifically version 2.7.13 (but it could be a newer one, I don't think it affects as it's a brand new codebase I need to set up). I've set up my package.json file this way:

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.3",
      "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.3",
      "angular-loading-bar": "github:chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar@0.8.0",
      "angular-sanitize": "github:angular/bower-angular-sanitize@1.4.7",
      "angular-ui-bootstrap": "npm:angular-ui-bootstrap@0.13.4",
      "angular-ui-grid": "github:angular-ui/bower-ui-grid@3.0.6",
      "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@0.2.15",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.5",
      "datatables": "github:DataTables/DataTables@1.10.9",
      "jeet": "npm:jeet@6.1.2",
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.1.4",
      "lodash": "npm:lodash@3.10.0",
      "normalize.css": "github:necolas/normalize.css@3.0.3",
      "rupture": "npm:rupture@0.6.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "angular-mocks": "npm:angular-mocks@^1.4.3",
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "browser-sync": "npm:browser-sync@^2.7.13",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I run `jspm update` (or `jspm install npm:browser-sync`) and it throws:

`err  Error locating github:component/global/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz.`

I have no idea how to solve this, honestly. Google doesn't throw much results so I'm practically blind.

I also have to add these packages (compatible with Angular 1.4.3 or something), but I'm trying to add them one by one now as adding them as a whole gave me a whole lot of errors which required me to input my github credentials, but it made no difference:

```
angular-mocks
babel-loader
browser-sync
chai
css-loader
file-loader
gulp
gulp-rename
gulp-template
gulp-todoist
http-backend-proxy
json-loader
jspm
karma
karma-chai
karma-chrome-launcher
karma-mocha
karma-mocha-reporter
karma-sourcemap-loader
mocha
ng-mock-e2e
node-libs-browser
raw-loader
run-sequence
style-loader
stylus-loader
yargs
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from an socket.io dependency updated in the jspm registry.

Now you should install it from github :

```
jspm install github:browsersync/browser-sync
```

and you can force the version, for eg.

```
jspm install github:browsersync/browser-sync@2.7.13
```